# C++ Array of an object (created) inside another Class

Tags: class, c++14, header-files

I have two classes inside a header file, the 2nd class dependent on the 1st. 
Including this header file in a .cpp file where I implement the constructor prototype for the Flight class. Compiling gives me the following error:

```
Error: no matching function for call to ‘Passenger::Passenger()’
      Flight::Flight(int maxPassenger, int flightNo) {
```

Here's the two classes in my header file

```
/*
 *Passenger Class:
 */
class Passenger
{
 public:
  int flightNo;
  string lastName;
  string firstName;
  int seatNo;
 public:
  Passenger(int flightNo, string lastName,string firstName,  int seatNo); 
};
/*
 *Flight Class:
 */
class Flight {
 public:
  int maxPassenger;
  int currentPos;
  int flightNo;
  Passenger list[20];
 public:
  Flight (int maxPassenger, int flightNo);
}
```

And Here's the constructor implementation:

```
Flight::Flight(int maxPassenger, int flightNo) {
  maxPassenger = maxPassenger;
  //  list = new Passenger [maxPassenger];
  flightNo = flightNo;
}
```

I can understand that there is a conflict in the constructors. But I can't figure out exactly what's wrong. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a constructor which takes zero arguments.

This code `list = new Passenger [maxPassenger];` invokes a constructor without any arguments `Passenger()` but there isn't one declared causing the error.

Comment: Will adding a constructor that names no value affect the list?
I'm trying to make a list that takes in Passenger Object, i.e It'll also hold the passenger name, seatNo and FlightNo. so that i can 
cout <<list[2].lastName
Is there any additional things i need to do?

Comment: No, it will not affect the list but the Passenger objects will not have any valid values for seatNo, FlightNo etc, it is up to you to initialize them correctly later on..